# How to create single backend website, iOS app and android app using flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, web, dart

I'm new to dart and flutter.

And I want to know how to create a website, iOS app and Android app with same backend/business logic using flutter.

Little guidance will be appreciable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can Create a Powerful Backend Using Firebase as a Backend service https://firebase.google.com/

As I'm Doing this for my Client it's very easy with Firebase.

In Firebase Settings Tab

- Click on Add App

[image: Adding App option in Firebase Setting]

you Can connect all the Service and access Database from any platform you just need link Them in Firebase.

- Firebase Provide Option to Add All Three Platforms

[image: Firebase Provide Option to Add All Three Platforms]

- 1. Connect Android App

[image: Connect you Android App]

- 2. Connect IOS App

[image: Connecting IOS App]

- 3. Connect Web Version

[image: Connecting Web Version]

- When i Starting it was mystery for Me... :D
  Hope This would help you.
- Helpful resource for learning
  https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC2d0BYlqQCdF9lJfydl_02Q
  https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCsBjURrPoezykLs9EqgamOA

Comment: So firebase as a single backend can handle all three : web,ios and android? Also, I have to write three different apps , right?

Comment: With Flutter you have to write only once, and Optimize for Each Platform.

Comment: I have machine learning code which is in python, so I was thinking of making flask API  connected  to my backend which I want to create in rails, And then the ios and android apps in flutter while backend as rails. how does it sound to you?

Comment: @nnd Well I don't much idea about that :D, but firebase as backend works fine :D

Comment: @nnd you are correct you can use your flask API with flutter.

Comment: I won't recommend firebase to anyone for production application.

Answer (score 2):

As a learning path to building cross-platform apps, I would start with the Flutter codelabs, in this order:

1. [Write your first Flutter app, part 1](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/first-flutter-app-pt1/#0)
2. [Write Your First Flutter App, part 2](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/first-flutter-app-pt2/#0)
3. [Write your first Flutter app on the web](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/codelab-web)
4. Then I would look at Firebase for the backend: [Add Firebase to your Flutter app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup) and [Firebase for Flutter](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#0).

For a nice introductory code example of a multi-platform app (Android, iOS, web, but without backend added) see the
[Provider Shopper](https://flutter.github.io/samples/provider_shopper.html) sample.

Lastly, I find the [Flutter Widget of the Week](https://youtu.be/b_sQ9bMltGU) series very useful for learning about the purpose and capabilities of each widget.

Comment: For a cross platfrom app, i would have to write different apps? like different app for ios and diff. for android?

Comment: Hi ndd, you would only write one Flutter app, but you would deploy 3 versions: Android, iOS and web. What I meant by the steps 1, 2, 3, 4 above is that that is a learning path to understanding how to build cross-platform Flutter apps. I will edit my answer for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You have to take care of few things:

1. Your UI must be responsive in nature, for that use *MediaQuery*
2. Render your UI based on the Platform.
3. Always check the packages you are using must support *flutter web* too, because there are a lot of plugins that don't supports flutter web yet.

Comment: so instead of opting for flutter web how about I make api in other framework like  flask or rails and them use that api in flutter to make apps ?

Comment: See both the things are different, flutter is used as a client application, while you can create backend in any framework of your choice.

Comment: so for example I have to write three different apps in flutter ios, web and android and then connect to a back end .. right?

Comment: since you are using flutter you can use single codebase with few configurations you can create ios, web, and android and since they are generated from single code base they will be having the same backend